# std::visit with passing pointer fails to compile under clang 13

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17

The following code compiles properly under [x64 msvc x19.30](https://godbolt.org/z/G9exoTca6) and [gcc 11](https://godbolt.org/z/nTc5xMsdh) but fails to compile under [clang 13.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/4r4b95hbc):

```
"error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::shared_ptr<std::pair<int, std::variant<Struct1, Struct2, UnsupportedStruct>>>' through variadic function;"
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

The following code produces different outputs depending on passing object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

struct Struct1{};
struct Struct2{};
struct UnsupportedStruct{};

using VarTypeData = std::variant<Struct1, Struct2, UnsupportedStruct>;
using VarType = std::pair<int, VarTypeData>;

namespace
{
    void print(Struct1&, std::shared_ptr<VarType> v) {std::cout << v->first << ": Struct1\n";}
    void print(Struct2&, std::shared_ptr<VarType> v) {std::cout << v->first << ": Struct2\n";}
    void print(...) {std::cout << "no implementation";}
}

int main()
{
    VarType data1 = std::make_pair(100, UnsupportedStruct{});
    auto pointerData = std::make_shared<VarType>(data1);
    std::visit([&pointerData](auto& c) {print(c, pointerData);}, pointerData->second);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    pointerData->second = Struct1{};

    std::visit([&pointerData](auto& c) {print(c, pointerData);}, pointerData->second);
}
```

This code [works fine for clang](https://godbolt.org/z/zTTvaoz6o) after dereferencing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

struct Struct1{};
struct Struct2{};
struct UnsupportedStruct{};

using VarTypeData = std::variant<Struct1, Struct2, UnsupportedStruct>;
using VarType = std::pair<int, VarTypeData>;

namespace
{
    void print(const Struct1&, const VarType& v) {std::cout << v.first << ": Struct1\n";}
    void print(const Struct2&, const VarType& v) {std::cout << v.first << ": Struct2\n";}
    void print(...) {std::cout << "no implementation";}
}

int main()
{
    VarType data1 = std::make_pair(100, UnsupportedStruct{});
    auto pointerData = std::make_shared<VarType>(data1);
    std::visit([&pointerData](auto& c) {print(c, *pointerData);}, pointerData->second);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    pointerData->second = Struct1{};
    
    std::visit([&pointerData](auto& c) {print(c, *pointerData);}, pointerData->second);
}
```

Comment: `void print(...)` is a C function, where variadic actually means the `<cstdarg>`'s parameter. It accepts only trivial types, which `std::shared_ptr` is not. So the behavior is undefined or only conditionally supported.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oh, thank you, I see. How can I change this default function to work properly with pointers as well?

Comment: Use normal template functions e.g. `template<class... Args> void print(Args&&...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @康桓瑋 for the answer.

this code does not work for clang, because of

```
void print(...) {std::cout << "no implementation";}
```

> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71185376/stdvisit-with-passing-pointer-fails-to-compile-under-clang-13?noredirect=1#comment125830891_71185376): void print(...) is a C function, where variadic actually means the
> 's parameter. It accepts only trivial types, which
> std::shared_ptr is not. So the behavior is undefined or only
> conditionally supported

So, the following changes [fix](https://godbolt.org/z/vPqxo5T6o) the problem:

```
template<class... Args> 
    void print(Args&&...) {std::cout << "no implementation";}
```